# Port re-direction from 80 to 443 in jboss 5.1 windows

Tags: jboss

I am using Jboss 5.1 in windows 64 bit. I have also deployed an application in the server.
The application is accessible via https using the port 443.I am not using any front-end web server.

I want the URL **http://example.com/context_root** to get re-directed to **https://example.com/contextroot**. It means the re-direction is from the default http port 80 to default https port 443.

When I hit the URL with the application's context root, I am getting the following error:
The page can't be displayed.

I have made the changes in server.xml file too for port re-direction:

```
<!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="80" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
  connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />
```

Can someone suggest me an optimal solution please?

Answer (score 0):

For the redirect to https you need add in `web.xml` of the application the following lines:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

See: [Specifying a Secure Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbm)

The documentation [The HTTP Connector](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html) say:

> redirect-port
>
> If this **Connector** is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is
>   received for which a matching `<security-constraint>` requires SSL
>   transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the
>   port number specified here.

Comment: I added this section in the application's web.xml and restarted Jboss.  But I am still getting the same error when I hit the URL with the application's context.

Comment: I am getting the following errors:
This page can't be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://URL-name is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

where,URL-name is application specific.

Comment: @SukanyaParam Check if you have enabled ssl in your server, test ssl access (https://example.com/contextroot) before redirection.

Comment: SSL is very much up . I say this because I am able to acces the application via https using the default port 443.You can see my first comment. But re-direction alone is failing. example.com/context root is not the original application's URL . I have  generalised the URL in my comments.My URL is entirely different but follows the same syntax as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I analysed and found a way to redirect the requests from 80 to 443.

In the bindings.xml file (C:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\conf\bootstrap) of the windows server, change the port from 8080 to 80 as this file will have a reference to server.xml file.

```
 <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
           <property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
           <property name="port">80</property>
```

After making the above change , I restarted the server once and hit the URL using the default port. It got redirected to https(443).

This helps in forcing all the non-ssl requests to be redirected in a secure way.